# Array Comparison Check

Tags: php, logic

I have 2 arrays:

The first:

```
$array1 = ("Key 1","Key 2","Key 3"); //is dynamic, so can range from 1 => many values
```

The second array is a databased value that will return an array based on however many keys the player has in the inventory.

```
$array2 = ("Key 1","Key 1","Key 2","Key 3","Key 3","Key 3") //in this case, the player DOES have all the keys.
```

My problem is, I can't figure out proper logic to compare these arrays, to see if `$array2` has at least one instance of that in `$array1`.

My comparison code I tried..

```
$check = array();
while ($k = mysql_fetch_array($array2)) {
    foreach ($array1 as $name) {
    if ((string)$name == (string)$k['name']) $check[] = true;
    else $check[] = false;
    }
}
foreach ($check as $bool) {
    if ($bool == false) {
        $return = false;
    } else {
    $return = true;
    }
}
return $return;
```

The problem there is that when I `print_r($check)`, I get numerous false, so even if the player contains all the right keys, the off comparison breaks the code and it returns false.

Any help with this comparison logic would be excellent, and if you need more details please let me know.

Comment: doesn't the array_intersect() function give you this?

Comment: How would I go about using that? `$result = array_intersect($array1,$array2); if ($result) { //do this }`?

Comment: http://php.net/array_intersect

Comment: than, in loop you can use in_array();

Comment: Also what are the credentials to get the 'best' result? Does every value of $array2 have to be in $array1?

Comment: @JoshBrody in order to return true, yes.

Comment: @PRPGFerret See my solution :) No weird array functions, and worked just great for me with my tests.

Comment: @PRPGFerret Your "in order to return true, yes" contradicts what is stated in the question.  Does every value of `$array2` have to be in `$array1`... or does every value of `$array1` have to be in `$array2`... will the answer be `true` or `false` when `$array2` contains values **not** in `$array1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is `in_array()` and here's the algorithm I used to solve it (thanks to the help of y'all)

```
while ($k = mysql_fetch_array($pkey)) { //turn returned list of player items into a new array
    $new_pkey[] = $k['name'];
}
foreach ($key as $name) { //search new array using the set list required to pass the check
    if (in_array($name,$new_pkey)) $check[] = true;
    else $check[] = false;
}
foreach ($check as $bool) { //search the check array to see if it contains a false. If so, break and return false
    if ($bool == false) {
        $return = false;
        break; //crucial bug -- would return true unless the last element was false. This lets any element be false and finally yield false
    } else {
        $return = true;
    }
}
return $return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original logic is about good. You made two mistakes:

1. You forgot to break out of the loop on encountering a true condition, so that the loop continues and sets the $check to false on the next iteration AND it would cause unnecessary bloat of the $check.
2. You set $check to false prematurely; a future match condition would flip over the bit in another place in the array, whereas the previous mismatches would have already set bits to false.

Try this:

```
<?php

$check = array();
foreach ($array1 as $name) {
    $check[$name] = false;
}

while ($k = mysql_fetch_array($array2)) {
    foreach ($array1 as $name) {
    if ((string)$name == (string)$k['name'])
    {
        $check[$name] = true;
        break;
    }
    }
}
foreach ($check as $bool) {
    if ($bool == false) {
    $return = false;
    } else {
    $return = true;
    }
}
return $return;
?>
```

And then you can do some optimizations as well. Instead of comparing each value read from DB with each value in $array1, you can check the values against only keys against which there is a false in the $check array. Your inner loops would run so much faster as you start filling up $check with trues.

Or if your inner loop is longish, you can consider sorting it so that the searching becomes faster. I am missing a built in binary search function or PHP does not has one built in; you probably need to cut and paste it from somewhere.

Or if not optimizing, at least do away with the inner loop with a single call to a function such as 'in_array'.